# Git clone using private key with password is stuck

Tags: git, github, ssh

I know that Git Clone can be performed using HTTPS instead of SSH, however this question is specifically related to cloning the repo using SSH keys.

OS Used: Windows 11

Steps performed:

1. ssh-key -o -t rsa -C "email_address" [Using git-bash], key saved to ~/.ssh/id_rsa specifying the passphrase as Password@123
2. id_rsa and id_rsa.pub are created in ~/.ssh folder
3. Copied contents of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to GitHub under Settings --> SSH and GPG keys --> SSH keys
4. Tried git clone git@github.com:someuser/someproject using the link under the Code/Clone section of Github repo
5. Expected behavior is that the code gets cloned after prompting for password, however it just says Cloning into ''... and is stuck forever at this point. Even the passphrase is not prompted for.

However in Step 1 if there is no passphrase specified for the ssh key generated and the remaining steps are performed as described, git clone is successful. Is there any reason why git clone fails with password protected public/private key pair?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to include the project name instead of ```/```?   i.e. ```git clone git@github.com:/<project>```

Answer (score 0):

Check what SSH is used (`where ssh` in a CMD)

- the one from Git for Windows: C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
- the [Windows OpenSSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui)

I don't have any issue with the first one (on Windows 11), while the [second can freeze on PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/836).

If you are on PowerShell, try the same git clone on `CMD`.